# How can my child class share idCounter with mother class?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, static, counter

I'm very new to programming and I couldnt find an exact answer for my question by googling it so hopefully i'll make it as simple as possible to understand.

My **public class MotherClass()** has *public int Id* which should show current number stored in *public static int idCounter*. I want to inherit/share same idCounter in my **public class ChildClass : MotherClass.**

So when i make for ex. 2 new MotherClass() objects and lets say 2 new ChildClass() objects, their Id's should be: 1,2,3,4 (shared) and not like 1,2 and 1,2 (different counter for each class).

This is what i have:

```
public class MotherClass(){
    public static int idCounter {get; set;}
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    static MotherClass(){
       idCounter = 1;
    }

   public MotherClass(string name, int id = -1){
   
     if(id == -1)
       Id = idCounter++;
     Name = name;
   }


public class ChildClass : MotherClass{
   
   public double Price { get; set; }

   public ChildClass(string name, double price int id =-1) : base(name,id){
     
      Price = price;

   }
```

}

Comment: One way is to add a property in child which is the parent class to make it easy to get properties from the parent.

Comment: If you really want to be a good programmer, don't google. Read books.

Comment: @jdweng
So you're thinking to add public MotherClass example { get; set;} in to ChildClass right?
I gave examples to class names here, in my case it would be weird to have that parent class in my child's property. So that wouldnt be my 1st solution for this if possible. 

Thanks for the reply, i will use this if nothing more suitable comes up.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy I dont have any books on me that can help me with this problem so google is option 1 in this case unfortunately.

Comment: You are confusing inherited classes and tree structures.  A parent child relationship is a tree structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
public class MotherClass
{
    public static int IdCounter { get; private set; } = 1;
    public int Id { get; } = IdCounter++;
}

public class ChildClass : MotherClass { }
```

Each time you create a new `MotherClass` or `ChildClass`, `IdCounter` will be incremented.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(new MotherClass().Id); // 1
Console.WriteLine(new MotherClass().Id); // 2
Console.WriteLine(new ChildClass().Id);  // 3
```

You should make the setter of `IdCounter` private then other classes cannot modify the value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Question:
Later on in ProgramUI class which is basically the Menu for operations with entities, i want to have an option for user to add/edit this instances of Mother and Child class (Id's too). If i make idCounter private set; and Id only get; , how do i change that ID later on ? 

Should i do something like this:

public int Id { 
  get { return IdCounter; }
  set { IdCounter = value; }
}

Comment: You would just add public setters, but that's probably not a good idea. If an Id is set to the same Id as an existing object you'd end up with duplicates.

Comment: That is true but i would make a Method later on that checks if user input for Id is a number already used for another object or not. Something like that i guess. At least thats an idea. Though maybe its best if Id's cannot be changed by users.

Comment: If Id is supposed to be unique then I would say definitely don't let users set that manually.